# CheckListBox not offering DataSource property

Tags: vb.net, datasource, checklistbox

I'm using VS2010 Pro (framework 4) to build a windows application. I'm trying to add a CheckListBox and set it's datasource to the contents of a table in an access back end, but the property isn't being diplayed. Does anyone know of a setting that I may need to adjust? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming you mean `CheckedListBox`, it has a DataSource property in version 4 of the Framework, see the [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox(v=vs.100).aspx). You can demonstrate it by coding in a new project `Dim cb As New CheckedListBox` and `cb.DataSource = someObject`

Comment: I've read the documentation. I know there is **supposed** to be a datasource property, I'm posting because there **isn't** an option to modify it.

Comment: I have read that DataSource does not show in the property grid for CheckedListBox or in Intellisense (I can't check that as I don't have access to Visual Studio at the moment). However, `cb.DataSource = myDataSourceObject` compiles and runs without throwing an exception.